# How to delete specific field using Objectify?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify, objectify-delete

I'm trying to delete specific field from my DB table. But unfortunately unsuccessfully. I tried this code:

```
Query<Movie> query = ofy().load().type(Movie.class).filter("name =", "movie name");
        QueryResultIterator<Movie> queryIterator = query.iterator();
        while (queryIterator.hasNext()){
            Movie m = queryIterator.next();
            if(p.getYear()!= null){
                ofy().delete().entity(p.getYear()).now();

            }
        }
```

I also tried this:

```
Movie m = ofy().load().type(Movie.class).id("movie id").now();
        List<Long> actors = m.getActor();
        ofy().delete().entity(actors).now();
```

But it also didn't work.
What did i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the property to delete to `null` and then `save` the entity. A `delete` will delete the whole entity, not any single property.

Example:

```
Movie m = ofy().load().type(Movie.class).id("movie id").now();
m.actors = null;
ofy().save().entity(m).now();
```

Comment: BTW, how can i delete an entire row by id?

Comment: @GidiSprintzin `ofy().delete().key(Key.create(YourEntityClassName.class, yourId)).now();`

Comment: Thnx again, but it didn't work. My code is:  `Query<Movie> query = ofy().load().type(Movie.class);

        for (Movie m : query) {
            List<String> list = m.getActors();
            String search = "actor name";
            for (String str : list) {
                if (str.trim().contains(search)) {
                    ofy().delete().key(Key.create(Movie.class, m.getId())).now();

                }

            }


        }`

Comment: @GidiSprintzin If my initial answer was helpful please accept it. I'm happy to help if you require assistance with the second problem. But please open a separate question for it. If we continue with comments this will become confusing very fast.